# Can we give sleep time less then one second in bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, command, kill

I have a `bash` script.I want to kill command in less then one second time.

```
#!/bin/sh
for ((i=0; i<=$1; i++)); do ssh "$2$i" 'uptime;free -m;mpstat;cat /tmp/db2.info'; done &
pid=$!
sleep 2
kill -9 $pid
```

Comment: `kill` kills immediately. Maybe you mean to use a shorter `sleep` time?

Comment: look http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50722/need-a-loop-to-sleep-for-a-fraction-of-second

Answer (score 7):

If you are using `sleep` from GNU coreutils, you can pass decimals as argument. Like this:

```
sleep 0.1
```

All Linux systems should have this version of sleep. If your code needs to run on BSD and other *NIXes too I would encourage you to write the script in a language like perl, python or ruby which has something like `usleep()`.